# Database connectivity in NetBeans IDE 6.9.1

Tags: ms-access, netbeans-6.9

what are the exact steps to connect a database prepared in MS Access to NetBeans IDE 6.9.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This outta do the trick

[NetBeans Info on DB](http://wiki.netbeans.org/AccessMssql)